# Php using a variable in a string (concatenation)

Tags: php, string-concatenation

why i can't use this code ? and could anyone tell me what is the correct code ?

```
$lfr_prfid = "profile='$log_id'";

$lfrsql = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='$log_id' AND accepted='1'";
$lfrquery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $lfrsql);

while ($lfrrow = mysqli_fetch_array($lfrquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$lfr_id = $lfrrow["id"];
$lfr_user1 = $lfrrow["user1"];
$lfr_user2 = $lfrrow["user2"];

$lfr_prfid += " OR profile='".$lfr_user1."'";

}
```

the last line i wrote this ( += ) and the code doesn't work so how can i do this in another way ? so i can use this in a SELECT statement .

```
$psql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ".$lfr_prfid." ORDER BY postdate DESC LIMIT 0,20";
$pquery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $psql);
```

Comment: Read about PHP's [operators](http://php.net/operators). The [string operators](http://php.net/operators.string) would be relevant in this case.

Comment: You urgently need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because this thing is riddled with [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). The [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method makes this safe and reliable.

Comment: Please accept the most helpful answer by clicking the checkmark to to the left of the answer, underneath the voting arrows. This will also award you some reputation points. If you haven't taken the SO tour, check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 4):

`$lfr_prfid.=`

Concatenate with `.` not with `+`. The `+` is concatenation in javascript.

so, in php: `$myVar.= 'foo';`

and in javascript: `myVar+= 'foo';`

#### Update based on your edit:

Please, DO NOT use that in a database query. Use prepared statements or your code is dangerous.

Comment: why it is dangerous ?

Comment: Read about prepared statements. It's more likely than not that someone could get use sql injection to do anything they want with your database. @Master

Comment: thanks very much , but is there another way to do that statement ?

Comment: @Master prepared statements. Google it.

Comment: @Master wrap the whole statement in this method: `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Or use prepared statements as m59 mentioned

Comment: thanks alot , i will google it and i will try to find another way to do that thanks so much :)

Comment: @imulsion Calling the escaping method manually should be an absolute last resort.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
$lfr_prfid .= " OR profile='".$lfr_user1."'";
```

Concatenation in PHP is done with `.`, not with `+=` as you have written.

Hope this helps!